# Add or remove an entry from a List type attribute in a DynamoDB table item

Tags: list, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a very simple class, with a string type primary key and List type attributes. I want to write an API for adding and removing an item from the attribute list, and saving the changes back to DDB.

The simplest solution I can think of is:

1. Read the list (if it exists)
2. If it exists, remove or add the item from the List type attribute
3. Put the modified object back

*Is there a cleaner/simpler way to do this via DynamoDB java API?*

Comment: please describe the simplier way that you are looking for :)

Comment: @ErbenMo I wanted to know if I could use UpdateExpression. But I just read the documentation thoroughly, and how delete works with a set type attributes. I see that my existing approach of reading, removing and updating is the only option I have. Will close the question now.

Comment: Do you know the index of the item to be removed, or can you instead map the items by some identifying key?

Comment: In step 2., it sounds like "it" refers to the list from 1, is that correct?

Comment: IMHO, the OP's Question can't really be answered without knowing the details I asked in above comments, thanks.

Answer (score -14, accepted):

I just read the UpdateItem API thoroughly which talks about deleting set type attributes:

> DELETE - Removes the attribute and its value, if no value is specified for  DELETE. The data type of the specified value must match the existing value's data type.If a set of values is specified, then those values are subtracted from the old set. For example, if the attribute value was the set [a,b,c] and the DELETE action specifies [a,c], then the final attribute value is [b]. Specifying an empty set is an error.

Comment: How does that help for List types?

Comment: The question was specifically about list types. This answer is about set types. This shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer is incorrect, the correct way of doing this is listed in the [DynamoDB UpdateExpression documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html#Expressions.Modifying.UpdateExpressions.DELETE)

You need to read the list then get the index of the item you're looking to remove then run `REMOVE list[index]` as an `UpdateExpression`

Comment: You can also use `DELETE`. Having `colors = ["red", "blue"]`,`DELETE colors :color` with `:color = "blue"` will work as expected.

Comment: @rolebi I don't think that's correct, did a test locally and got `Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: DELETE, operand type: LIST`

Comment: Is `colors` a `LIST` ? You have to create it using `$doc['colors'] = new Aws\DynamoDb\SetValue(['red', 'blue'])` using the AWS PHP SDK

Comment: `.withStringSet("colors",  new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("red", "blue")))` for the Java SDK

Comment: My bad, in my example `:color` in `DELETE colors :color` should also been sent as a list instead of a string to make it work : )

Comment: @rolebi - even sending it as a list doesnt work. Same error ```Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: DELETE, operand type: LIST```

sent it like ->
':metadata': [role]

Comment: @rolebi i'm happy to update my posted answer but AFAICT your other solution doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Working example in PHP https://gist.github.com/rolebi/e0c56113f5e36246bbf5f84d3e94627b

Comment: I am reading the link to dynamodb docs, and lets say i have a list of data [1,2] and two users, both would like to delete the first number in the list, and both will update delete with list[0] to erase the number "1", one of them will delete the correct number, and the second will delete the number "2" how can we make sure to delete only what we want to delete, and not delete anything if it's not there? normally with relational db I would use id, but here we don't have any

Comment: You should use a ConditionExpression to protect against someone else changing the data at the same time

Comment: DELETE only works for sets, for Lists, the only option would be REMOVE

Comment: @rolebi your answer is confusing here - working example you shared clearly uses sets ("SS") and not lists ("L")

Comment: @LoganMay sure, this will only work if the "attribute list" (as referred by the OP) is a "list" of unique strings / number / binaries, which is probably not the case.

Comment: @rolebi what I'm saying is your code uses sets, keyed with "SS". As David Christie pointed out, DELETE doesn't work on sets. It has nothing to do with the uniqueness of values in your lists, i.e. whether or not your List is abstractly a set by having unique values. It has do to with what data type you're using in Dynamo, a string set ("SS") or a list ("L")

Comment: @LoganMay it may not have been clear but by saying <"list" of unique strings / number / binaries> (please note the quotes) I was referring to the fact that if such usage arise you would be able to model that through a SS and thus would be able to handle the alteration of such "list" much more easily than by using the L type. So yes I understand the fact that SS and L are different, even if three years ago my initial comment hadn't taken into account the fact that the OP may have referred to a list of data that may not have been represented as an SS.

Comment: could you do `REMOVE :listItem` then set listItem to whatever the item is so you dont have to retrive the index? As far as I can tell, `list[index]` would return the item anyways so...

Answer (score 6):

You can use `SET` operator to add element in the attribute list. But for that you have to retrieve the existing list first then append new element in the list. Suppose you have a attribute named `active_user` which contain the list of active users.

```
previous_list = "#a"
query = "SET %s = list_append(%s, :new_user)" % (previous_list, previous_list)
user_table.update_item(
    Key={
        # primary key
    },
    UpdateExpression=query,
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        '#a': 'active_user',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':new_user': new_user_model
    }
)
```

You can use `REMOVE` operator to remove or delete an element of the list. But you have to find the index of the element because `REMOVE` operator removes the given index of the list.

```
#user_index is the position of the target user in the list

query = "REMOVE active_user[%d]" % (user_index)
user_table.update_item(
    Key={
        # primary key
    },
    UpdateExpression=query
)
```

Here is `REMOVE` operator [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE) and `SET` operator [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET).

Comment: Why do you say, "you have to retrieve the existing list first"?  Isn't `SET` a write-operation?  Where is the read-operation for to the "retrieve" you mention? (also, what language is this?  I just can't recognize personally, thanks).

Comment: Regardless, +1 for `REMOVE` in the 2nd half of this Answer.

Answer (score 1):

For those using [PynamoDB](https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can do:

Remove from ListAttribute (list):

```
obj = Model.get(model_id)
index = obj.list.index(value)
obj.update(
    actions=[
        Model.list[index].remove()
    ]
)
```

Append to ListAttribute(list):

```
obj = Model.get(model_id)
obj.update(actions=[
    Model.list.set(
        Model.list.append([value])
    )]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who arrives here and is still stuck using node and `DocumentClient`. I could not make any sort of `ExpressionAtrributeVariables` or `ExpressionAttributeNames` interpolation work, so ended up just using string concatenation.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
  var data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  var recordID = data.idOfSomeRecordWithAList
  var item = data.someListItemToDelete

  // Get the current list
    var listParams = {
        TableName: 'someTable',
        Key: {
            'id': recordID
        }
    }
    var records = await dynamo.get(listParams).promise();
    var list = records.Item.someList;

    // Remove the selected item from the list
    var indexToRemove = list.findIndex(i => i === item);
    // Note the standard string concatenation here 
    // I could not get any sort of #value or :value interpolation to work!!
    var UpdateExpression = 'REMOVE someList['+indexToRemove+']';
    var removeListItemParams = {
        TableName: 'someTable',
        Key: {
            'id': recordID
        },
        UpdateExpression
    }

    try {
        await dynamo.update(removeListItemParams).promise();
    } catch (e) {
        // This is helpful if running in Lambda and need to check logs.
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Also `REMOVE` is for lists `DELETE` is for sets (and has a special syntax [[1]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#:%7E:text=return%2Dvalues%20ALL_NEW-,DELETE%E2%80%94removing%20elements%20from%20a%20set,-Important)).