# Dynamodb How to perform update in a list element in an item?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, amazon-dynamodb

I am storing data in a list element. That list attribute consists of multiple fields like year and name. Is there any way I can delete only the rows where year is 2018 like in relational databases??

Data is stored in this manner in which ID is primary key and some other fields as password, city etc. Below is how data is stored in quarters.

```
{
  "q1risk" : "0",
  "q1targets" : [ ]
}
UpdateItem succeeded:
{
  "q2risk" : "100.0",
  "q2targets" : [ {
    "level" : "Basic",
    "year" : "2017",
    "name" : "1",
    "completed" : "0",
    "category" : "US"
  }, {
    "level" : "Basic",
    "year" : "2017",
    "name" : "2",
    "completed" : "0",
    "category" : "US"
  }, {
    "level" : "Basic",
    "year" : "2018",
    "name" : "3",
    "completed" : "0",
    "category" : "US"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258682/add-or-remove-an-entry-from-a-list-type-attribute-in-a-dynamodb-table-item), according to the [DynamoDB UpdateExpression documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE.RemovingListElements), you can remove individual elements from the list using `REMOVE ListAttribute[index]`.

However, there doesn't appear to be a way to conditionally delete list elements based on a condition.

Your best bet to minimize read/write throughput is to:

1. Query for the item with a CONTAINS filter condition and a projection expression on the list attribute.
2. If the item is found, it contains at least one element you want to remove, so find the indices of elements you want to remove.
3. Use `REMOVE` with the indices to remove those elements from the item's list attribute.