# How to delete a element from LIST in dynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have an atrribute with LIST data type be like:

```
"ketban": {
    "L": [
      {
        "S": "01012018000007"
      },
      {
        "S": "01012018000009"
      },
      {
        "S": "01012018000006"
      },
      {
        "S": "01012018000005"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now i want to delete a item and result be like:

```
"ketban": {
    "L": [
      {
        "S": "01012018000007"
      },
      {
        "S": "01012018000009"
      },
      {
        "S": "01012018000006"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I can do it with SET data type but not with LIST data type.
Please help me!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41274242/1591917

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add or remove an entry from a List type attribute in a DynamoDB table item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258682/add-or-remove-an-entry-from-a-list-type-attribute-in-a-dynamodb-table-item)

Comment: You’re very welcome, I’ve flagged this as a duplicate