# dynamodb removing specific item from a list without collisions

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am using dynamodb with the python api, and have a list attribute, the list contains complex data in it.

I would like to be able to remove a specific item.

I found [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE) tutorial explaining how to remove an item from the list by it's index.

And found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258682/add-or-remove-an-entry-from-a-list-type-attribute-in-a-dynamodb-table-item) SO question regarding the situation.

Both the tutorial and the SO question show how to remove an item from a list by it's index, I have a more specific situation, where two users can use the same dynamodb table at once, and both of them might be trying to remove the same item, when using index, it can cause a situation as the following: having a list [1,2,3] two users want to remove the item "1" and using remove list[0], the first user removes the item 1, but now the list is [2,3] and the second user removes the item "2".

I found that you can remove a specific item by it's value when using dynamodb set datatype, but there is no set that can contain a complex data, only binary, str and number and I need to store something that is more like: {"att1":[1,2,3], "att2":str, "attr3":{...}} and nested.

How can I remove an item without the risk of removing another item by the index if someone already removed it before me causing me to remove the wrong item?

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember exactly is dynamodb can return hash of the existing record

If not you can try to add it as additional field and create a key by this property
And then you can update your object with where clause
something like

`aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name ProductCatalog \
    --key '{"myHash":{"N":"125948abcdef1234"}}' \
    --update-expression`

Idea is if object was already updated by someone hash also should be different

Comment: This will prevent me from updating the item if it way changed in any way, not only in the defined way of deleting the item i wanted to delete... this is not answering the question sadly.

Comment: You are the person who defines content for hash algorithm :)

Comment: Well, that will be great :-) could you be more specific for the way to define it to suit the needs here?

Comment: add a new property HashedArrayValue and key in dynamodb
Recalculate this propery every time you are updating your record
Something like:
HashedArrayValue = SomeHashCalculator.Calculate(SomeJsonSerializer.Serialize(myNewArrayVersion)); ?