# Deleting Element inside a list DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

According to the link below in DynamoDB, you can only remove elements if you know the index of the array/list.

[Add or remove an entry from a List type attribute in a DynamoDB table item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258682/add-or-remove-an-entry-from-a-list-type-attribute-in-a-dynamodb-table-item)

What I would like to know is how do you prevent index out of range error.

Or even worst...removing the wrong item because the index number changed.

This could happen when multiple users request removal of data at the sametime but their index number changed while the lambda function was working.

The only thing I can think of is

Request to see the table, thats call number 1 $$$

Confirm that the index is still valid

Then make the change that's call number 2 $$$

And this solution only reduces the time between check and update 
It is still not a complete fix.

Is this an acceptable error ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [REMOVE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE) to delete by index can lead to inconsistencies like you have mentioned.

If possible, it would be best to use a Set type so you can use the [DELETE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.DELETE) keyword where you can delete by value instead of index.

If not possible, you can add an extra layer of protection by including a [ConditionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) to the `UpdateExpression` to verify that the state of the list is the same as you expect.  You could do something like verify the value at the index is the value you expect and/or verify that the list is the same size as you expect.