# Delete element in LIST (ARRAY) into DynamoDB with Dynamoose

Tags: arrays, amazon-dynamodb

i use dynamodb with dynamoose. The problem is in this model

```
{
  "root": [
       {
           "element": "test"
       },
       {
           "element": "test2"
       },
       {
           "element": "test3"
       }
   ]
}
```

I try to delete "test2" with

```
await DataModel.update(
{ id: dataId },
{
  $REMOVE: {
    root: [
      {
        element: "test2",
      },
    ],
  },
}
);
```

But remove root property, I try other options, without luck

Comment: You cannot delete items from an array like this in DDB. You need to remove the item from your array in your application, then set the entire updated array.

Comment: Hi Richard, ok, but with $ADD, i can add the element to the LIST, without update entire array (or dynamoose do this in the back) why $REMOVE not work similar?

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken, there is an option to remove an item, but you have to do so by index, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258682/add-or-remove-an-entry-from-a-list-type-attribute-in-a-dynamodb-table-item)

Comment: ok, so, if i have a big object, for example {
  "items": [
    {
      "property1": {
        "otherElement": [
          {
            "moreElements": {}
          }
        ]
      },
      "property2": {
        "otherElement": [
          {
            "moreElements": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
The unique options, is get 50mb of register, update, and set entire object again?

Comment: I'm confused, I don't quite follow. DDB only allows records of up to 400KB, so I don't understand what you're talking about re: 50mb.

Comment: I create "SingleTable" model, i have for example, one object with nested objects, because the dynamodb register is a "domain model" in this domain model, i have an array of elements. I need a CRUD of this array